# Is it possible to chain Lodash Array methods with es6 Array methods

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I want to chain Lodash Array methods interchangeably with ES6 Array methods without using `_chain` and in a Functional Programming style.

I want to do this:

```
import {flatMap} from 'lodash';

const result = my2DimensionalArray.flatmap().map(i => {
 return `${i}-blergh`;
});
```

I get this isn't really possible without extending native Array Protoytpe.

I'm currently working like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

_(my2DimensionalArray).flatMap().value().map(i => {
  return `${i}-blergh`;
});
```

Can I improve this somehow?  How are other people doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Because `_.flatMap()` returns an array, you can use JS map with it like this:

```js
const arr = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [9, 11, 13, 15]];

const result = _.flatMap(arr) // returns an array
  .map(i => `${i}-blergh`); // JS map

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you're using a lodash's chain, use lodash's `_.map()` by moving `_.value()` to the end of the chain:

```js
const arr = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [9, 11, 13, 15]];

const result = _(arr) // start a chain
  .flatMap()
  .map(i => `${i}-blergh`) // lodash's map
  .value(); // end the chain

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

> **Note:** The array methods - map, filter, reduce, reduceRight, forEach, every, and some are part of ES5, and not ES6.

Comment: Wow, so simple. And if the Lodash method you choose to use appeared in the middle of the chain?

Comment: As long as you're returning an array, you can chain JS methods. Whenever you use lodash chain, you can chaing only lodash methods. So you can chain together many lodash methods, end the chain with a value to return an array, and continue to chain JS method. You did that with your 2nd example.